# Error after updating PIL (Pillow) from 2.3.0 to 2.7.0

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I had a question regarding handling .eps-files yesterday - you can find it here: [With Python`s PIL, how to set DPI before loading an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344258/with-pythons-pil-how-to-set-dpi-before-loading-an-image)

I was loading an .eps-file and processed it which is working. Today I tried to update PIL (Pillow) to version 2.7.0 - after that reading the .eps-file isn`t possible anymore.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img_pil.py", line 25, in <module>
    img = Image.open('epstest.eps')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 2274, in open

IOError: cannot identify image file 'epstest.eps'
```

**Code:**

```
img = Image.open('epstest.eps')
```

Is this a bug, or do I miss something?

Comment: What happens if you downgrade to 2.3.0 again? `pip install pillow=2.3.0` should do the trick, based on my quick Google search.

Comment: @WayneWerner After downgrading the file can be read...

Comment: Looks like a case for a [bug report](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues)

Comment: @WayneWerner Thanks - i submitted it.